# многомодульный Maven проект

Tags: java, maven

Возникла такая проблема при создании проекта Maven с несколькими дочерними модулями. Имеется структура:

```
├─── Root
│   ├─── Engine
│   ├─── Mod1
│   ├─── Mod2
```

Где:

- **Root** - Корневой Pom проекта
- **Engine** - набор интерфейсов и абстрактных классов
- **Mod1** - реализация интерфейсов и классов под одни задачи
- **Mod2** - реализация интерфейсов и классов под другие задачи

При этом у `Mod1` и `Mod2` есть свои внутренние, отдельные друг от друга зависимости к нужным им библиотекам.

По поводу структуры, возможно вопрос не стоит (если только с ней не связано решение), у всех модулей прописан общий `<parent>` на `Root`, а в нем эти же модули прописаны вот так:

```
<modules>
    <module>Engine</module>
    <module>Mod1</module>
    <module>Mod2</module>
</modules>
```

Также к `Mod1` и `Mod2` модуль `Engine` подключен как `<dependecy>`

Прикол в том, что по итогу мне нужно получить два `.jar` файла которые НЕ содержат ВСЕХ зависимостей, но каждый из них содержит `Engine` и конкретную реализацию, т.е. типа таких 2 файла:

```
├─── Jar1.jar
│   ├─── Engine
│   ├─── Mod1

├─── Jar2.jar
│   ├─── Engine
│   ├─── Mod2
```

Зависимости самих реализаций вообще никак не трогая, они тут нужны для разработки, а там где проект будет запускаться они уже подключены.

Может кто подсказать как это сделать? Увы на запросы в гугле постоянно находится "сборка многомодульного webapp через maven", но там не подходит решение, т.к. у меня всё-таки не веб-приложение

Answer (score 0):

Короче разобрался. Костыль, конечно, но работает:
В `Mod1` и `Mod2` просто добавил:

```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>../Engine/target/classes/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Может кому полезно будет (но опять же, не претендую что это верное и уж тем более единственное решение)